# Using Keycloak for Wildfly Applications - Authentication Error

Tags: java, wildfly, keycloak

I'm writing a plugin for Keycloak which basically a Wildfly application itself. 
When I try to deploy the application to running Keycloak, I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR]    JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05128: Failed to read challenge file [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/tmp/auth/local6441877703083959873.challenge (No such file or directory)]
[ERROR]    DIGEST-MD5: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: Server rejected authentication
```

I tried to add new user with roles but didn't work. Can someone explain me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thank you,

UPDATE:
Here is some part of my massive standalone.xml

```
 <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <server-identities>
                    <ssl>
                        <keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                    </ssl>
                </server-identities>
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <http-upgrade enabled="true"/>
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>
    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">
            <web-context>auth</web-context>
            <providers>
                <provider>
                    module:car.hey.keycloak.actuator
                </provider>
                <provider>
                    module:car.hey.keycloak.insideman
                </provider>
                <provider>
                    classpath:${jboss.home.dir}/providers/
                </provider>
            </providers>
            <master-realm-name>master</master-realm-name>
            <scheduled-task-interval>900</scheduled-task-interval>
            <theme>
                <staticMaxAge>2592000</staticMaxAge>
                <cacheThemes>true</cacheThemes>
                <cacheTemplates>true</cacheTemplates>
                <dir>${jboss.home.dir}/themes</dir>
            </theme>
            <spi name="eventsStore">
                <provider name="jpa" enabled="true">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="exclude-events" value="[&quot;REFRESH_TOKEN&quot;]"/>
                    </properties>
                </provider>
            </spi>
            <spi name="userCache">
                <provider name="default" enabled="true"/>
            </spi>
            <spi name="userSessionPersister">
                <default-provider>jpa</default-provider>
            </spi>
            <spi name="timer">
                <default-provider>basic</default-provider>
            </spi>
            <spi name="connectionsHttpClient">
                <provider name="default" enabled="true"/>
            </spi>
            <spi name="connectionsJpa">
                <provider name="default" enabled="true">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="dataSource" value="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS"/>
                        <property name="initializeEmpty" value="true"/>
                        <property name="migrationStrategy" value="update"/>
                        <property name="migrationExport" value="${jboss.home.dir}/keycloak-database-update.sql"/>
                    </properties>
                </provider>
            </spi>
            <spi name="realmCache">
                <provider name="default" enabled="true"/>
            </spi>
            <spi name="connectionsInfinispan">
                <default-provider>default</default-provider>
                <provider name="default" enabled="true">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="cacheContainer" value="java:jboss/infinispan/container/keycloak"/>
                    </properties>
                </provider>
            </spi>
            <spi name="jta-lookup">
                <default-provider>${keycloak.jta.lookup.provider:jboss}</default-provider>
                <provider name="jboss" enabled="true"/>
            </spi>
            <spi name="publicKeyStorage">
                <provider name="infinispan" enabled="true">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="minTimeBetweenRequests" value="10"/>
                    </properties>
                </provider>
            </spi>
            <spi name="x509cert-lookup">
                <default-provider>${keycloak.x509cert.lookup.provider:default}</default-provider>
                <provider name="default" enabled="true"/>
            </spi>
            <spi name="hostname">
                <default-provider>request</default-provider>
                <provider name="fixed" enabled="true">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="hostname" value="localhost"/>
                        <property name="httpPort" value="-1"/>
                        <property name="httpsPort" value="-1"/>
                    </properties>
                </provider>
            </spi>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:bean-validation:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:core-management:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:${jboss.server.data.dir}/keycloak;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:4.0">
            <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-config-smallrye:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-health-smallrye:1.0" security-enabled="false"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-metrics-smallrye:2.0" security-enabled="false" exposed-subsystems="*" prefix="${wildfly.metrics.prefix:wildfly}"/>
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0">
            <deployment-permissions>
                <maximum-set>
                    <permission class="java.security.AllPermission"/>
                </maximum-set>
            </deployment-permissions>
        </subsystem>
```

Comment: Please provide your standalone or domain xml

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've added xml file to description @ArielCarrera

Comment: Check your filesystem grants for user from which keycloak runs. Also note that you should use admin user for deploying artifacts to Wildfly. Anyway i think this is only "artifacts to Wildfly deploying issue" (Keycloak application itself is not the case).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem may be due to using EJB and trying to make a remote call in your application.
When you use remote EJBs, they will be connected by the remote connector defined in your xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns = "urn: jboss: domain: remoting: 4.0">
<http-connector name = "http-remoting-connector" connector-ref = "default" security-realm = "ApplicationRealm" />
</subsystem>
```

In this case, verify the configuration of your ejb client.
You should have a file named *jboss-ejb-client.properties* (It should be located in the *src/main/resources* folder).
Take in account to disable some configurations:

- SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT
- SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS

#### *Jboss-ejb-client.properties* example:

```
endpoint.name = client-endpoint
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED = false
remote.connections = default
remote.connection.default.host = 127.0.0.1
remote.connection.default.port = 8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT = false
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS = false
remote.connection.default.username = username
remote.connection.default.password = password
```

Replace in the above example the connection host, port and the user credentials.

> In this example, the connection is not encrypted but it can have SSL
>   enabled too.

Take into account that if the connection requires authentication, you need to add a user to your WildFly via the add-user.sh (or add-user.bat) script.

You can also try to replace your ejb remote access with a local one (@Local instead of @Remote).

I hope this helps, otherwise try to share a sample reproducer (eg github) and I will try to help you.